# User.where(:id =>1).where(:id => 2) with ActiveRecord doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Simply put:

```
pry(main)> User.where(:id =>1).where(:id => 2).first
 User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
 #user 2 is returned
```

How can I make it run:

```
pry(main)> User.where(:id =>1).where(:id => 2).first
 User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 AND "users"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
#this way no user is returned, because I'm narrowing it down as much as possible
```

Comment: You do know that your second query will always return no records?

Comment: From @a'r (very valid) point, only the answer of Bassam Mehanni below is correct, both others do not do what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, I want to restrict, i.e. I have 2 scopes using id, and they are overlapping each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of [arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) you can do this:

```
t = User.arel_table
User.where(t[:id].eq("1").and(t[:id].eq("2")))
```

Comment: Actually it's an `and` instead. Please update your answer so I can select it. :)

Comment: Hmm Actually thinking about it, can I do this on 2 where calls?

Comment: @PedroNascimento an and on the same column is impossible, you are saying id = 1 and id = 2, that means id is 1 and id is 2 at the same time, that can never happen, it has to be an or if you wanna select both users with id 1 and users with id 2

Comment: I know it can never happen; but if you add a couple of method calls that can possibly search for different values on the same column, this is entirely possible. i.e. `User.find_some_stuff(current_user).do_lots_of_stuff(params)` if the latter method do something the first one also does, I'll be, in the end, in the same problem, i.e. one `where` is overwriting an attribute search on another `where`.

Comment: I've updated the question in case it's not clear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: my only issue with the answer is that I can only do it using one `where` call, not two. Is it possible to use `.and` somehow with two `where` methods chaining?

Comment: @PedroNascimento according to the readme on the project I am referencing you can chain, there example is users.where(users[:name].eq('bob')).where(users[:age].lt(25))

Comment: You can chain, but not on the same column. If I use `:name` in both `where`s, I'll just get the last.

Comment: looks like ActiveRecord has a safe guard against this, so that when you chain where on the same record it does a replace instead of adding and, you might be out of look here, sorry

Comment: I'll accept the answer as this is as closer as I can get. Thank you!